# I wanted to do a post request with django using ajax

Tags: javascript, django

I want to make a request with the **method** **post** using **ajax**. But my **django server** returns a **Forbidden error (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): / Post** / it asks me for the **csrf token**

here is my code:

Answer (score 0):

```
{% block java %}
<script type="text/javascript">

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()


document.getElementById('form').addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();

        xhr.onload = function(){
                console.log("succes")
                
        }
xhr.open("POST", {% url 'post' %})
xhr.send()


});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```